# How would applications on the iPhone adapt to a bigger iPhone screen?

Tags: iphone, screen

A lot of rumours are going around about Apple and the iPhone 6, one if which is that the iPhone 6 could have a bigger (6 inch) screen.

Being an iOS developer I know that most apps on the iStore use images and sometimes custom controls which are perfectly optimised to display correctly on current screen sizes of the iPhone.

If Apple decides launch an iPhone with a bigger screen size surely application images would start to pixelate, and controls would stretch out of proportion.

My question is, how does Apple handle bigger screen sizes to keep apps from pixelating and stretching out of proportion and displaying incorrectly on devices?

Thanks

Comment: Just as an aside I find it extremely unlikely they would introduce a 6" iPhone. It seems like it would be far too close to the 7" iPad mini, and Apple historically tried to keep different models fairly well differentiated.

Comment: Agreed, on the other hand it seems likely that they would introduce the 6" to keep up with the ever increasing screen sizes of their main competitor (Samsung). If Apple decides to stay with 4" displays they would need to consider major hardware advantages/features over their competitors. Im not saying Samsung (or others) would take the market based on their screen size, but screen real-estate plays a big role.

Comment: I'm going to shut this down temporarily for several reasons. 1) It's not clear if you are a developer looking for concrete advice today how to inform your efforts. If so -> stack overflow (or maybe UX?) 2) Unless you pin down some specific circumstances what "bigger size" means your "pixelate" and "proportion" posts might not even matter. Our general advice is to not ask open ended hypothetical questions - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask but I wanted to explore some avenues to edit this into shape if you have a practical question you need assistance answering.

Comment: I have edited my question, tubedog gave me the exact answer I was looking for, they 'letterbox' the screen to keep the correct proportions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Apple were to increase the screen size, it would likely be done in the same fashion by which they have done it each previous time - in such a way that apps, while maybe not looking as great as they could, are functional and visibly proportional.

When they introduced the Retina screen on iPhone 4, they kept the screen size the same but doubled the resolution. So while pre-Retina apps might have looked a bit blurry, they were still functional and had the exact same proportions.

This same process occurred when the Retina screen was applied to the iPad 3.

When the 4" screen was introduced on iPhone 5, they kept the same width but increased the height of the screen. Functionally this meant that all apps operated identically, with the sole difference being black letterboxing at the top and bottom of the screen. But since the pixel density did not change, nor the width, apps looked exactly the same with no proportion issues or visual degradation.

Apple has shown themselves to be very thoughtful about making such changes and there is no reason to believe they wouldn't be going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Apple would do what Apple wants to do. It's not like they are asking us for a choice.

There is one example on screen increase : 3.5" to 4" with the iPhone 5. 
In this particular case there was no strech. On non iPhone 5 optimized app, there are 2 black space below and above the app.